# Set input value for post from results of javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with a search function that returns a table of search results. For each row of the table, there is a drop-down for the amount to donate and a Donate button. I would like to post the value from the row upon clicking Donate, but am unable to figure it out.

I have the confirm alert working with all the correct row information on click, but I am unable to set the hidden input value from within that function. So I made a second function `results()` and tried to set the value from that, but it's not working. If I just set it with some text (`document.getElementById('donation').value = "some_text"`), that works fine. But I would like to set the data from the row in which the button was clicked and set it as a value for POST.

This is my code:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Donate
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/donate" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="name"
            placeholder="What animal would you like to support?" type="text" size="40">
        </div>
        <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <table class="table" id="sponsor_table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Scientific Name</th>
          <th scope="col">English Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Red List Category</th>
          <th scope="col">Donation</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    {% for animal in animals %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ animal.canonicalName }}</th>
        <td>{{ animal.vernacularName }}</td>
        <td>{{ animal.redlistCategory }}</td>
        <td> <select id="price" name="price" onChange="calc();">
            <option value="">Amount</option>
            <option value="25">$25.00</option>
            <option value="50">$50.00</option>
            <option value="100">$100.00</option>
            <option value="200">$200.00</option>
            <option value="500">$500.00</option>
            <option value="1000">$1000.00</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <form action="/donate" method="post">
            <td><input name="donation" type="hidden" value="">
            <button id="donation" class="btn btn-primary" name="donation" value="Donate" >Donate</button></td>

        </form>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
    $("#donation").on('click',function(){
         // get the current row
         var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");

         var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
         var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
         var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(2) option:selected").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
         var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
         confirm("Would you like to support the " + col2 + " " + col1 + " population with a donation of " + col3 + "?");
    });
});

function results()
{
                var rowId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
                var data =  document.getElementById(rowId).querySelectorAll(".row-data");

                var species = data[0].innerHTML;
                var name = data[1].innerHTML;
                var category = data[2].innerHTML;
                var amount = data[3].innerHTML;
                return species;
            } ;

document.getElementById('donation').value = results();

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

**SOLVED:**

```
            <form action="/donate" method="post">
                <td><input name="donation" type="hidden" id="test" value="">
                <button id="donation" class="btn btn-primary" name="donation" value="Donate" >Donate</button></td>

            </form>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
        $("#donation").on('click',function(){
             // get the current row
             var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
    
             var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
             var col2=currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
             var col3=currentRow.find("td:eq(2) option:selected").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
             var col4=currentRow.find("td:eq(3)").text(); // get current row 3rd TD
             confirm("Would you like to support the " + col2 + " " + col1 + " population with a donation of " + col3 + "?");
             document.getElementById('test').value = [col1, col2, col3];
        });
    });
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you are asking, from what i get, you want to get the value from the `<select id="price">` and set that to an `<input type="hidden">`?

Comment: By the way you are selecting the `<button id="donation">` instead of the `input:hidden` on javascript when you are setting the value.

Comment: "I have the confirm alert working with all the correct row information on click, but I am unable to set the hidden input value from within that function." <= My gut reaction to this statement is that the reason you may have been having an issue with this is because the element you are clicking for the event is a `<button>` which will submit the form.  AFAIK, when a normal form submit happens, it will grab the input values at that point.  If you modify them within an event handler, they will not be reflected in the request.  You would need to cancel the request, change the value, and ...

Comment: ... submit again, bypassing the handler.  This may or may not be the associated issue, since your event handler is a `click` handler, and not a `submit` handler, but I would definitely test that out.

Comment: Thank you @Francisco! I added an `id="test"` to the to the `<input type="hidden">`, and then set the value within the `$("#donation").on('click',function()` and it worked. No need for the `results()` function. I added solution above